# MySQL turn JSON_ARRAY of ids into JSON_ARRAY of values [MySQL 8]

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mysql-8.0

I have a JSON_ARRAY of ids in the form of [1,3,...]. Each value represents an id to a value in another table.

```
Table: pets
id | value
 1 | cat
 2 | dog
 3 | hamster

Table: pet_owner
id | pets_array
 1 | [1, 3]
 2 | [2]
 3 | []
```

What I want to get when I query pet_owners is the following result:

```
Table: pet_owner
id | pets_array
 1 | ["cat", "hamster"]
 2 | ["dog"]
 3 | []
```

How do I run a sub-select on each array element to get its value?

Answer (score 0):

As JSON goes, it is always a pain to handle

When you need also all that have no pets, you must left Join the owner table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE pet_owner (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `pets_array` JSON
> );
>
> INSERT INTO pet_owner
>   (`id`, `pets_array`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '[1, 3]'),
>   ('2', '[2]'),
>   ('3', '[]');
>   
>
>
>
> CREATE TABLE pets (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `value` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO pets
>   (`id`, `value`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'cat'),
>   ('2', 'dog'),
>   ('3', 'hamster');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> t1.id,
> JSON_ARRAYAGG(
>   p.`value`
> ) AS pets_array 
> FROM(
> SELECT * 
> FROM pet_owner ,
> JSON_TABLE(
>       pet_owner.pets_array , "$[*]" 
>       COLUMNS(IDs int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY )
> ) AS J_LINK ) t1
> LEFT JOIN pets p ON p.id =t1.IDs
> GROUP BY 
> t1.id
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | pets_array        
> -: | :-----------------
>  1 | ["cat", "hamster"]
>  2 | ["dog"]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=468ebb5c26d582078e357721aae6fc3c)*

A normalized Table would spare you to convert the data into usable columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can join on [`json_contains()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html), then re-aggregate:

```
select po.id, json_arrayagg(p.value) as owners
from pet_owner po
left join pets p on json_contains(po.pets_array, cast(p.id as char))
group by po.id
```

Note that, unlike most (if not all!) other databases, MySQL does not guarantee the ordering of elements in an array generated by `json_arrayagg()`: that's just a fact we have to live with as of the current version.